# How do I reproduce experiments or specify the nodes execution order in Kedro?

Tags: kedro

Since kedro determines the execution graph based on the nodes input/outputs, the order of executions is non-deterministic. It can vary between runs.

Even when I set a seed I may sample different data in different runs.

Let says I have 3 nodes that do not depend on each other.
1st run: A->B->C
2st run: B->A->C

I will get different results simply because the random generator sequence is not the same.

Comment: This is an intentional behaviour as the dependency resolution in Kedro is completely data-driven. The recommended option would be to use dummy inputs / outputs as suggested by @pascalwhoop below (option 2).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options but there is no "out of the box" solution from kedro to enforce ordering of nodes without having dataset based dependencies.
You could:

- make each node a 1-node-pipeline itself and run them in sequence in python
- pass dummy inputs & outputs between them (such as an empty dataset or just a `""`
- make them all one node

Comment: I'd say that from Kedro perspective the second option is much more preferable, since options 1 and 3 effectively remove the Kedro Pipeline abstraction from the scope of the project, making the node dependency graph definition entirely manual process. It is still partly the case for the dummy dependencies, but at least it still leverages Kedro pipeline for execution order / vizualisations.

Comment: option 2 for a long pipeline would means i have to add a dummy arguments for a lot of function, which is quite inconvenient. However, make sure something is deterministic is quite useful especially for ml project.

Comment: Updated: As of Kedro 0.18.3 the order is deterministic if you are using SequentialRunner (default)